# Similar problem to Knight's tour

Tags: recursion, backtracking

You have board size and one Knight but what is different is that when you move it you have to duplicate the knight and the 2 duplicates have to be in valid position from the knight
This gets repeated until the board is filled with knights just like visited in the original problem but both duplicates can be moved, once. The knights can't be on already occupied positions.

I wrote some code for it that worked for some starting positions, the problem is that I was taking only two first possible positions from my generated list, when I tried 2 last I managed to solve another ones.

So I changed the code to loop over combinations and try them out, but this seems to be taking too much time, so this approach is most likely wrong.

I would really appreciate if anyone could point me to a right direction of solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Clarifying question: so in step $i$  of the process (starting from 0) you have $2^i$ knights, and then before step $i+1$ starts you must add $2^i$ new knights, where each of the new knights is an empty square and must be matched to a different knight from the step $i$ that is 1 knight-jump away. If all of this is correct, then what exactly is your question? For which initial positions in an $8 \times 8$ grid there is a solution until filling the grid? the same for $2^n \times 2^n$ grids?

Comment: Hey, sorry. I will try to clarify. The boards sizes can be 1 to 9, and you are given position of one initial knight on the board, and you are supposed to duplicate the knight so you will have 3 knights, the one you started with is considered frozen and can't be used anymore but the duplicates can and the same will apply to them, if it's possible to place 2 knights. You can't place 1 knight only, it always has to be 2 and you are supposed to do this until you fill the board with knights meaning annex it.